# How to display output with a % sign. eg: 90%

Tags: sql

the below query gives me result as 90 AND NOT 90%.

```
SELECT
 CAST(convert(decimal(20,10),[Total]) as int) AS 'TT'
,cast((convert(decimal(20,10),([Count_Checked_Out]/convert(decimal(20,10),[Total])))* 100) as int) AS '%_Checked_Out'
```

Comment: it is a int value if you want percent sign just append it

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in sql query you can do something like this

```
select concat(90,"%") as percent_value;
```

But as @Joel Coehoom pointed out you should do this in your presentation layer

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/191808/0

Answer (score 2):

If you want formatting, of any kind, you must convert the value from a number type, like `int`, to a string type, like `nvarchar`. Exactly what this looks like depends on what specific database platform you're using.

But in most cases, you're better off leaving this work for your client code or reporting tool.